# transformStamped get rotation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
when i got this code

```
    geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transformStamped;
        try{
          transformStamped = tfBuffer.lookupTransform("tf-a", "tf-b",
                                   ros::Time(0));
        }
        catch (tf2::TransformException &ex) {
          ROS_WARN("%s",ex.what());
          ros::Duration(1.0).sleep();
          continue;
        }
double roll, yaw,pitch;
     tf::Quaternion q();
     q = transformStamped.transform.getRotation();
     tf::Matrix3x3 m(q)
     m.getRPY(roll,yaw,pitch);

     ROS_INFO("angles in degree: roll >%f<, yaw >%f<, pitch >%f<", roll, yaw, pitch);
```

it returns:

```
  error:
 ‘geometry_msgs::TransformStamped_<std::allocator<void>
 >::_transform_type’ has no member named ‘getRotation’
       q = transformStamped.transform.getRotation();
```

but here http://answers.ros.org/question/193409/reading-a-specific-tf-frame/ its used ? Also transformStamped.getRotation() does not work.

i simply want to get the angle between both tf frames in degree ? but how?

thanks

EDIT:
this code works for me, if there is better way, please tell me:

```
 double r,y,p;
 double d1,d2,d3;
 geometry_msgs::Quaternion q = transformStamped.transform.rotation;
 tf::Quaternion tfq;
 tf::quaternionMsgToTF(q, tfq);
 tf::Matrix3x3(tfq).getEulerYPR(y,p,r);
 d1 = angles::to_degrees(y);
 d2 = angles::to_degrees(p);
 d3 = angles::to_degrees(r);
 ROS_INFO("euler-angles::to_deg y >%f<, p >%f<, r >%f<", d1, d2, d3);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237426/transformstamped-get-rotation/) by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 406 on 2016-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are confusing the data types (well, they are confusing indeed).

There is `geometry_msgs::TransformStamped` and `tf::StampedTransform` in ROS. The first is just a container (C++ ROS message representation) used for data serialization, while the second is a full-featured class that allows to manipulate transformation matrices etc.

The code you gave the link to is using `tf::StampedTransform`. Also it uses the old `tf` methods, where `lookupTransform` accepts only `tf` data types and has the following signature:

```
void lookupTransform(const std::string& target_frame, const std::string& source_frame,
                       const ros::Time& time, StampedTransform& transform) const;
```

while the one you are trying to use is from `tf2`:

```
virtual geometry_msgs::TransformStamped 
    lookupTransform(const std::string& target_frame, const std::string& source_frame,
                    const ros::Time& time, const ros::Duration timeout) const;
```

P.S. Most of the examples you find on ROS Answers are likely to be for previous version of `tf`.

---

EDIT:

If the only thing you need is Euler angles, then it is enough. Though, if you are going to work with the whole transform, then it is better to convert the whole `geometry_msgs::TransformStamped` to `tf::StampedTransform`, or acquire the latter directly with `tf::lookupTransform` (in tf1).

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2016-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0